# SSRS - Set different padding/margins based on view type

Tags: reporting-services

My report is setup perfectly for print layout.  When I look at the report in my SSRS server as a webpage everything, tables/charts etc, are on the very left edge of the screen.  Is there a way I can change padding or margins based on the view I'm in?  So if I'm in the standard web view everything is bumped over half an inch, but if I'm in print preview that extra half inch is gone?

I might be missing the point though.

Comment: By "standard web view" do you mean Report Manager page e.g. `http://yourserver/reports` or Visual Studio's ReportViewer control? Also, which browser are u using and which version of SSRS?

Comment: Yeah, like I went to http://yourserver/reports and ran the report.  Everything on the report hugs the left of the screen, but when I go to save as pdf, everything looks right.  I was wondering if there was a way to set margins based on each view type.

Comment: which browser are u using and which version of SSRS? It could be simple browser incompatibility.

Comment: looking through IE9, SSRS is probably 2008

Comment: It could be compatibility issue indeed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511(v=SQL.100).aspx list max compatible browser IE7. 2008 R2 probably compatible with up to IE8. You may want to try running your browser in compatibility mode, but it is not guaranteed

Answer (score 0):

SSRS reports have 2 size types:

1. Interactive Size - specifies the default size of pages when rendering the report in an interactive renderer.
2. Page Size - specifies the width and height for the report

These sizes are set at the Report properties level. Adjusting these should give you the desired results.